# Llamar vista parcial desde un botón flotante

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC 5 tengo un botón materialize el cual me despliega dos botones de los cuales al hacer clic en uno de ellos me debe llamar a una vista partial como popup. El código de los botones es este:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="action-btn-wrapper">
            <div class="fixed-action-btn my-custom-btn horizontal">
                <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
                    <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">playlist_add</i></a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Al final del Index tengo este código:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div id="myModalContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ya tengo creada mi vista partial, solo falta llamarla, la vista partial es un Create.

```
@model Demo.ServiciosDominio.Dtos.ProveedorDto

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ProveedorDto</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RazonSocial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RazonSocial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RazonSocial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Direccion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Direccion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Direccion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telefono, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telefono, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telefono, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Necesito poner algo en el controller ProveedorController? como un

```
return PartialView()
```

Ya puedo llamar al modal pero me sale vacio

```
<li><a class="btn-floating red" onclick="llamarVistaParcial();" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="material-icons">playlist_add</i></a></li>
```

Comment: La persona que voto negativo sería bueno que nos explicara el por qué, a mi parecer es una pregunta muy válida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para llamar una vista parcial, lo haremos modificando solo unas pequeñas partes del código que actualmente tienes, realmente, ya tienes casi todo listo.

Partiendo del hecho que debemos invocar un `Html.RenderAction` con los parámetros `Action` y `Controller` (*en este caso le puse de nombre `Create` a tu `Action` pero ahí debes poner el adecuado*):

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div id="myModalContent">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("Create", "Proveedor"); }
    </div>
</div>
```

El código de tu `Controller` quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
public class ProveedorController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView("CreatePartialView");
    }
}
```

Donde `CreatePartialView` es el nombre de tu vista parcial.

El contenido ese `PartialView` se va a renderizar en el `div` `<div id="myModalContent">`.

Comment: Funciono pero para que sirve esta linea de código entonces en le js function llamarVistaParcial() {
            var laURLDeLaVista = '@Url.Action("CreatePV", "Proveedor")';
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                type: "GET",
                url: laURLDeLaVista,
                data: {},
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#resultado').html('');
                    $('#resultado').html(response);
                }
            });

Comment: Ese código hace una petición `ajax` y supongo que espera recibir un resultado variable, algo así como un HTML dinámico ya que finalmente el resultado lo pone con `$('#resultado').html(response);`, es decir, ese resultado se va a renderizar en `#resultado` :)

Comment: No sera que mi vista partial debe tener un id="resultado?"

Comment: Nesecito que funcione con ajax

Comment: No es necesario, con lo que tienes actualmente te puede funcionar a la perfección. De hecho yo quitaría ese ajax para que no cause conflicto

Comment: Dame unos momentos y vemos la forma en que podemos ajustarlo a un ajax. Yo propuse esa solución porque en la pregunta no lo menciona, mientras tanto ve editando tu pregunta para saber exactamente el objetivo del ajax ;)

Comment: El error era por que faltaba cerrar en la Función un }

Comment: Excelente mi estimado Pedro :D

Comment: Igual sale como un sombrero en el popup

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas para que funcionen tus botones es agregar el campo de `href` en el boton haciendo referencia al modal (`#myModal`) ejem.

`<a href='#myModal' class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">playlist_add</i></a>`

Ahora, para que la libreria tome ese boton como un `modal-trigger` es necesario que lo establezcas al cargar la pagina, agrega las siguientes lineas en tu código.

`$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-floating.red').leanModal();
});`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-floating.red').leanModal();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="action-btn-wrapper">
      <div class="fixed-action-btn my-custom-btn horizontal">
        <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
          <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
        </a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='#myModal' class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">playlist_add</i></a></li>
          <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div id="myModalContent">Modal Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Creo que la pregunta del OP es respecto a como llamar a una vista parcial (en .NET) desde el botón flotante para mostrar la vista en la modal.

Comment: Estoy llamando una vista parcial modificare la pregunta